# Connection compressed with DEFLATE, hosted on Heroku but rack middleware doesn't report using Rack::Deflater

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, rack, deflate

Chrome claims that the connection to my site is compressed with DEFLATE. The issue is that I am not using Rack::Deflater (I don't see it when I run rake middleware). My staging site has pretty much the exact same configuration as my production site ... and that connection is not compressed.

I'm not sure what is causing the connection to my production site to be compressed - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which stack are you on, Bamboo or Cedar? Are your environments using different stacks?

[Bamboo has automatic gzipping](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing-bamboo) I believe.

Cedar does not, you need to include the middleware as you describe.